# Neo4j Create Nodes without Creating Duplicates Nodes

Tags: neo4j

I am very new to this. So sorry if it seems dumb. I have a file with user log records which has two columns, "User ID" and "User Name", basically it's a record of when people log in and out. I need to create nodes using the "User Name" and "User ID", how do go about this? I read somewhere to use `OPTIONAL MATCH` but it didn't work. Here's what I wrote:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '' as row
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:User) AS nd 
WHERE nd is NULL
CREATE (n:User{user_name:row.User_Name}),(r:UserId{user_id:row.User_ID})
```

It still created the same amount of nodes. I'd appreciate if anyone could help me with this. I can use `apoc.mergeNode` to delete the duplicates after creating the nodes, but it will be much more convenient if I could just do it all in one statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `MERGE` and there will never be any duplicates:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '' as row
MERGE (n:User{user_name:row.User_Name})
MERGE (r:UserId{user_id:row.User_ID})
..
```

Comment: Wow. That was a super simple solution mate. I tried it out and it works. Thank you so much.